# Other JSP pages are opening in same jsp page

Tags: jsp

I am using JSP for different login user to open their own individual content.I used session and invalidated at the logout.jsp. So it is not opening the jsp pages after logout by copying the url and try to run in the browser. But i need a solution that, When i enter through login with one type of user (for eg:http://localhost:8080//CEO.jsp) it works fine if i give (for eg:http://localhost:8080//Staff.jsp) it is opening in same CEO.jsp page. I need that to not open . Please help me in this..

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"    import="Accessing.UserBean"%>
    <%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/birt.tld" prefix="birt" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript" >
javascript:window.history.forward(1);
</script>
<style>
.title
{
width:769px;
height: 65px;
margin:15px auto;
}
.left
{float: left;
margin: 20px 50px 20px 30px;
padding: 0 0 25px 15px;
width:700px;
border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
background-color: #CC6699;
color: #990066;
}
.right_side
{
float:right;
width:580px;
color: #000000;
background-color: #FFFFFF;
margin: 20px 0px 20px 10px;
padding:0px 0px 25px 15px;
border:1px solid #CCCCCC;   
}
</style>
</head>
<%
UserBean currentUser =(UserBean)session.getAttribute("currentSessionUser");%>
<% 
try{
    if((String)currentUser.getRoles()!=null)
 {
  %>
<body bgcolor=#CC9999>

<div class="title"> 


<div class="rightside">
<a href="signingout.jsp">Logout</a>
</div>
</div>
<div class="left">
<birt:viewer id="birtViewer" reportDesign="BankCredit.rptdesign"
pattern="frameset"
height="450"
width="700"
format="html">
</birt:viewer>
</div>
<%
    }
  else
      response.sendRedirect("signin.jsp");
    }
catch(Exception e)
    {
  out.println("<br><br><br><br><br><br>");
  out.println("<center><b><font color=red>SORRY!! ACCESS DENIED.INVALID USER.</font></b></center>");
  out.println("<br><br>");
  out.println("Please click here for <a href=signin.jsp><b>Login</b></a>");
 }
%> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is the double slash `//` in the urls after the port no. 8080 a typo ? and can you share some code ?

Comment: Yes i redirecting to the three different users it works but the only problem that when i open the page of a single user and changing the name of the other jsp page it showing that page contents but the page of the previous jsp is still working. For eg:http://localhost:8080//CEO.jsp and changing to http://localhost:8080//Staff.jsp) Its thier in the CEO . jsp page but showin the staff . jsp content.Help me please

Comment: no its single / by mistake i typed it

Answer (score 0):

My approach to solving a problem such as this would be to cut the page down, removing more and more fragments until it's clear which lines are having the bad effect.

It should be possible to get it down to one or two lines which really show the problem.